# Arrows in tables, or matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, arrows, tikz-arrows

I have been experimenting with LaTeX for a couple of years now, but still consider myself a neophyte.

I spent much of yesterday trying to create a table. I am trying to create a table with three columns, and five rows, each of the columns should contain a left justified text string. To the right of the text in the second text column I would like to draw a vertical arrow from the middle of row 2 to the middle of row 5, going vertically from top to bottom. To the right of the text in the third column I would like to draw an arrow going from the middle of row 5 to the middle of row 2. One further wrinkle is that I need to include multiple lines of text in these two columns.

My gut feeling is that this should be possible using Tikz, and I can come close, but I just can not seem to quite get this right. Is Tikz the right way to go? Should I add two extra columns for the arrows, or is there a way to include this arrow in the same cell as the text, offset by 0.5em. Can Tikz handle multi-line nodes. I am completely new to Tikz

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That is, show us your code!

Answer (score 10):

Here are two different solutions.

The first solution uses a `tabular` environment and `\tikzmark` to control the position of where the arrows should go:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%%
  my dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},
  >={To[scale=2]}
  }

\def\tikzmarkhf#1{\hspace{\fill}\tikzmark{#1}}
\def\tikzmarkup#1{\raisebox{2ex}{\tikzmark{#1}}}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{p{2in}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}

\def\longtexta{the lazy dog jumped over the sleep fox}
\def\longtextb{To the right of the text in the second text column I would like to draw a vertical arrow from the middle of row 2 to the middle of row 5, going vertically from top to bottom. To the right of the text in the third column I would like to draw an arrow going from the middle of row 5 to the middle of row 2. One further wrinkle is that I need to include multiple lines of text in these two columns.}
\def\longtextc{My gut feeling is that this should be possible using Tikz, and I can come close, but I just can not seem to quite get this right. Is Tikz the right way to go?}
\def\longtextd{Should I add two extra columns for the arrows, or is there a way to include this arrow in the same cell as the text, offset by 0.5em. Can Tikz handle multi-line nodes. I am completely new to Tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{PP@{\hspace{1.5cm}}P}
 \longtexta & \longtextb                               & \longtextc \\
 \longtexta & \tikzmarkup{A1}\longtextc\tikzmarkhf{A2} & \tikzmarkup{C1}\longtextc\tikzmarkhf{C2} \\
 \longtexta & \longtextb                               & \longtextc \\
 \longtextb & \longtexta                               & \longtextc \\
 \longtexta & \longtextb                               & \tikzmarkup{B1}\longtextc\tikzmarkhf{B2} \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]

  \node (A)  at ($({pic cs:A1}-|{pic cs:A2})!0.5!(pic cs:A2)$) {};
  \node (Bl) at ($({pic cs:B1}|-{pic cs:B2})!0.5!(pic cs:B1)$) {};

  \draw[arrows=-Stealth] (A) -- ($(A)!0.5!(A-|Bl)$) -- ($(A|-Bl)!0.5!(Bl)$) -- (Bl);

  \node (C)  at ($({pic cs:C1}-|{pic cs:C2})!0.5!(pic cs:C2)$) {};
  \node (Br) at ($({pic cs:B1}-|{pic cs:B2})!0.5!(pic cs:B2)$) {};

  \draw[arrows=Stealth-] (C) -- ($(C)+(0.75cm,0)$) -- 
                         ($(Br)+(0.75cm,0)$)  -- (Br);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note: I define two macros `\tikzmarkup` and `\tikzmarkhf`.  The *up* version raises the position of the `\tikzmark` vertically.  The *hf* version  essentially shoves the `\tikzmark` against the right hand side of the minipage it inhabits.  (I wanted to define something like `\tikzmark*` to do this, but kept running into parsing errors.)

`pic cs:C1` names the node created by `\tikzmark{C1}`.  `\tikzmark` uses the `pic` canvas; so to be able to refer to the node from outside of where it was defined, you'll have to reference it in terms of the canvas it was rendered on.

[image]

The second solution is done completely within a `tikzpicture` and uses the facilities of the `fit` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%%
  my dot/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},
  >={To[scale=2]}
  }


\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{p{2in}}

\def\longtexta{the lazy dog jumped over the sleep fox}
\def\longtextb{To the right of the text in the second text column I would like to draw a vertical arrow from the middle of row 2 to the middle of row 5, going vertically from top to bottom. To the right of the text in the third column I would like to draw an arrow going from the middle of row 5 to the middle of row 2. One further wrinkle is that I need to include multiple lines of text in these two columns.}
\def\longtextc{My gut feeling is that this should be possible using Tikz, and I can come close, but I just can not seem to quite get this right. Is Tikz the right way to go?}
\def\longtextd{Should I add two extra columns for the arrows, or is there a way to include this arrow in the same cell as the text, offset by 0.5em. Can Tikz handle multi-line nodes. I am completely new to Tikz}

\def\aepar#1{\parbox[t]{2in}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (Q1) at (0,0) {};

  \foreach \myA/\myB/\myC [count=\mycnt from 1] in {\longtexta/\longtextb/\longtextc,
                                                    \longtexta/\longtextc/\longtextc,
                                                    \longtexta/\longtextb/\longtextc,
                                                    \longtextb/\longtexta/\longtextc,
                                                    \longtexta/\longtextb/\longtextc
                                                    }
  {
    \node[anchor=north west] (A\mycnt) at (Q\mycnt) {\aepar\myA};
    \node[anchor=north west] (B\mycnt) at ($(A\mycnt.north east)+(2ex,0)$) {\aepar\myB};
    \node[anchor=north west] (C\mycnt) at ($(B\mycnt.north east)+(1cm,0)$) {\aepar\myC};
    %% use "fit" to get the correct size of the row
    \node[fit=(A\mycnt)(B\mycnt)(C\mycnt)] (row\mycnt){};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\next{int(\mycnt+1)}
    \node (Qt\next) at ($(row\mycnt.south)+(0,-2ex)$) {};
    \node (Q\next)  at (Qt\next-|A\mycnt.west) {};
  }

  \draw [arrows=-Stealth]
        (B2.east) -- ($(B2.east)!0.5!(B2.east-|C5.west)$)
                  -- ($(B2.east|-C5.west)!0.5!(C5.west)$)
                  -- (C5.west);

  \draw [arrows=-Stealth]
        (C5.east) -- ($(C5.east)+(0.5cm,0)$)
                  -- ($(C2.east)+(0.5cm,0)$)
                  -- (C2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think, even if I misunderstood quite what you wanted, you should get enough of an idea from these two examples to create what you need.

I suspect that using a `tikz` matrix might work even better, but I have not played much with that and it's very unfamiliar territory.

**UPDATE**

Plain straight arrows from one row to the next are not very attractive.  Here they are if you want them:

```
\draw[arrows=-Stealth] (B2.east) -- (C5.west);
\draw[arrows=-Stealth] (C5.east) -- (C2.east);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `out` and `in` directives to `to` as in

```
\draw [arrows=-Stealth]
      (B2.east) to [out=-60,in=120,looseness=0.70] (C5.west);

\draw [arrows=-Stealth]
      (C5.east) to [out=60,in=-60,looseness=0.5]
                (C2.east);
```

which is a bit more attractive.

[image]

Possibly, you have the following in mind:

```
\draw [arrows=-Stealth]
      ($(B2.east)!0.5!(B2.east-|C5.west)$)
      --
      ($(C5.west-|B2.east)!0.5!(C5.west)$);

\draw [arrows=-Stealth]
      ([xshift=0.5cm]C5.east) -- ([xshift=0.5cm]C2.east);
```

[image]

(Better images to be posted later, I can't do that from my current work station.)

Comment: Many thanks for your solutions, they have given me much to think about. How would I go about removing the elbows in the arrows? I simply need a straight vertical arrow? I think that it has something to do with the \node at code, but am not sure.

Comment: @grazer I've added a few more examples of how to work this from within the `tikzpicture` environment.  Something very similar can be done in the example with an `overlay` on the `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the arrows by using the TikZ nodes created by `nicematrix` under the cells of the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,ext.paths.ortho}

\newcolumntype{P}{p{2in}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.75}

\def\longtexta{the lazy dog jumped over the sleep fox}
\def\longtextb{To the right of the text in the second text column I would like to draw a vertical arrow from the middle of row 2 to the middle of row 5, going vertically from top to bottom. To the right of the text in the third column I would like to draw an arrow going from the middle of row 5 to the middle of row 2. One further wrinkle is that I need to include multiple lines of text in these two columns.}
\def\longtextc{My gut feeling is that this should be possible using Tikz, and I can come close, but I just can not seem to quite get this right. Is Tikz the right way to go?}
\def\longtextd{Should I add two extra columns for the arrows, or is there a way to include this arrow in the same cell as the text, offset by 0.5em. Can Tikz handle multi-line nodes. I am completely new to Tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{PP@{\hspace{1.5cm}}P}
 \longtexta & \longtextb & \longtextc \\
 \longtexta & \longtextc & \longtextc \\
 \longtexta & \longtextb & \longtextc \\
 \longtextb & \longtexta & \longtextc \\
 \longtexta & \longtextb & \longtextc \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [-Stealth, shorten < = 3pt, shorten > = 3pt]
    \draw (2-2.east) -|- (5-3.west) ; 
    \draw (5-3.east) -- ++(6mm,0pt) |- (2-3.east) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]